# Use of TSA locks embedded in luggage in Europe?

Tags: luggage, europe, tsa

I bought a luggage with a TSA lock on the side of the luggage, which holds the zipper.

Can I use this lock, or will they break my entire luggage if they need to inspect it (considering most European airports seem not to have access to a TSA masterkey).

Comment: It's not a duplicate, because I'm specifically asking for luggages with built-in locks.

Answer (score 4):

As far as I know, outside of the US, you can lock your luggage with whatever lock you like. I always (outside the US) use non-TSA locks where ever I go, nobody ever asked about it. If they really want to inspect your luggage they should ask you to open it for them.

So yes, use your TSA lock.

P.S. There may be more people with access to the TSA masterkey than you think.

Comment: "If they really want to inspect your luggage they should ask you to open it for them". I struggle to beleive that ever happens. If you lock your luggage, be prepared for secruity to break into it (that even happens with TSA locks in the US)

Comment: But what will they do with built-in luggage locks then? How do they break it? Worried about my luggage.